# Storing last line of file in an array continuously in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So i have a little issue with some PHP read functionality. What I am trying to do is basically grab data into an array from a file that is being continuously updated from a python script reading values from a micro controller. So basically, the file would look something like this.

```
ID, Datetime, Count, Name
ID, Datetime, Count, Name
ID, Datetime, Count, Name
```

What i need is for it to read the new line that is being added in (eof) and store it into an array. So what i have so far is allowing read access into the file

```
  <?php
$myfile = fopen("read.txt", "r")
```

For the storing the lines in an array i figured something like an array map would be efficient

```
$result = array();
 // some loop
  $parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2)));
  $result[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
```

However i am not to sure on how to structure the loop to have it read the new line that is being updated in the file without exiting the loop.

```
while (feof($file)) {
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Would keeping track of the last 'offset' (size of file) enable you to 'reposition' using `seek`, so that you are only reading the 'extra' information in the file?

Comment: fseek($fp, $pos, SEEK_END);  ??? something like this or ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

1. Read the lines of the file to an array using `$lines = file("filename");`.
2. Use the `$lines[count($lines) - 1]` to get the last line?
3. You can even `trim` off the empty lines before you wanna do this.

**Trim Empty Lines**

Use this function:

```
$lines = array_filter($lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is continually being appended, you'd have to read until you hit the end of file, sleep for a while to let more data be appended, then read again.

e.g.

```
while(true) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
       ... process data
    }
    sleep(15); // pause to let more data be appended
}
```

However, I'm not sure if PHP will cache the fact that it hit eof, and not try again once the sleep() finishes. It may be necessary to record your current position `ftell()`, close the file, reopen it, then fseek() to the stored location.

Comment: i can't really have it sleep because it is going to be apart of a near real time system ... for like 8 hours but it will have like 2500 lines....

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this solution

```
$filename = "file.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$lines = explode("/n", fread($file, filesize($filename)));
$last = $lines[count($lines)-1];
```

If the file is going to get big, it could take some time to parse, so its also possible to adjust the fread() function so it only reads the last 100 characters for example.

Comment: i will try this out .. it makes sense to read the last 100 characters would possibly improve my systems time.. thanks ill update with an answer